# mongodb simplify grouped results

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection using following schema to record pto entries:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58e2b888c97157e9aca48361"
    },
    "pto_date": "11/07/2017",
    "pto_type": "Sick / Personal",
    "pto_duration": 3,
    "pto_user": "amanda@push10.com",
    "pto_approved": "false"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58e2b90fc97157e9aca48362"
    },
    "pto_date": "02/03/2017",
    "pto_type": "Vacation",
    "pto_duration": 2,
    "pto_user": "amanda@push10.com",
    "pto_approved": "true"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58e3c91ac2397604bf40ff0a"
    },
    "pto_date": "04/04/2017",
    "pto_type": "Sick / Personal",
    "pto_duration": 5,
    "pto_user": "amanda@push10.com",
    "pto_approved": "true"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58fa1e4c382e17705cd723d5"
    },
    "pto_date": "04/21/2017",
    "pto_type": "Sick / Personal",
    "pto_duration": 2,
    "pto_user": "amanda@push10.com",
    "pto_approved": "true"
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "58fa1e80382e17705cd723d6"
    },
    "pto_date": "04/21/2017",
    "pto_type": "Sick / Personal",
    "pto_duration": 2,
    "pto_user": "greg@push10.com",
    "pto_approved": "false"
  }
]
```

Using the following aggregation pipeline I am able to get all entries matching a specific user grouped by approval status and also totaling the hours.

```
db.pto.aggregate([
    { 
        $match: { 
            pto_user : "amanda@push10.com" 
        } 
    },
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id : "$pto_approved", 
            total : { 
                $sum : "$pto_duration" 
            } 
        } 
    }
])
```

My results are as follows:

```
[
    { "_id" : "true", "total" : 9 }
    { "_id" : "false", "total" : 3 }
]
```

My objective is to further simplify these results as such:

```
{ "approved" : 9, "pending" : 3 }
```

I'm not sure if there is an additional step I can add to my pipeline to acheive this or if I am approaching this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB 3.4, shell

```
db.your_col.aggregate([
    {$match: {pto_user: "amanda@push10.com"}},
    {$group: {_id: null,
              approved: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$pto_approved', 'true']}, '$pto_duration', 0]}},
              pending: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$pto_approved', 'false']}, '$pto_duration', 0]}}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0}}])
```

BTW, it would be better if you store 'false'/'true' as boolean values and pto_date as Date object